# View Hierarchy Debugger - re-center or pan the heirarchy

Tags: ios, xcode

One problem I freqently run into in XCode's view hierarchy debugger is the portion of my view that I'm interested in is wayyyy off to the right or left edge of the xcode window.

As yet, I've been unable to find any key combination that allows you to 'pan' or 'drag' or 're-center' the displayed view hierarchy.   The only options appear to be to rotate the hierarchy, or trim it from front or back, but nothing at all about actually moving the hierarchy back to the center of the xcode 'debugger window'

Anyone have a clue how to do that? or if it's possible?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view is scrollable. So just scroll however you would normally do a horizontal scroll:

- If you have a track-pad, use 2-finger drag horizontally.
- If you have a scroll-wheel on your mouse, hold Shift and turn the scroll-wheel.

Comment: And of course there may be other ways of scrolling that involve other hardware that I don't know about!